# Что делать, качаю библиотеку, она не качается

Tags: python, pycharm

Я пытаюсь установить библиотеки, но получаю ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Comment: Зонтик, снизу в терминале

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors